# Which smart contract should I use to wrap Eth

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, decentralized-exchange

I need Weth for my dapp. So I looked at how AirSwap converts ETH to Weth. On the Rinkeby testnet, AirSwap calls this [contract](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xc778417e063141139fce010982780140aa0cd5ab#code) and uses the "deposit" function. I see from the code how this would work. Also I can see that this contract is owned by 0x.

My question is: Can I just call that exact contract for my Dapp too? Is this the recommended way to exchange Weth for Eth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2`.

A while ago, Will Warren (CEO of 0x) [made a call for people to use a canonical WETH contract](https://blog.0xproject.com/canonical-weth-a9aa7d0279dd). Since then, nearly all Dapps have used this.

You will even see your Rinkeby WETH address in that article.